# Network being disabled after shutting computer

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm running on a Dell Studio with a disable wireless switch.  "Why do we even have that switch?" I wonder, but that's besides the point.


Anyways, sometimes I just close my computer without shutting it down.  [image: Network problem]  When I do, and then I open it the next day, it seems there's a 50-50 chance that the network ends up like the upper right of the image included.  Even though I click "Enable Networking", nothing happens.  I can fix this using `sudo service network-manager restart`, but I'd like to know why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: It is indeed curious that I came here today to ask this exact question.  This came up as a suggestion.  I'm gonna try your command line trick.  If that works, I'll consider that a good enough work around.  It's a lot better than restarting the machine every time it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that has been around for a while and has seemed to come back in 14.04.
Initially it was fixed in version 13.11.

The original bug report (which was confirmed fixed) can be found:
[here on launchpad #1184262](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1184262)

The new bug report for this occurrence can be found: 
[here on launchpad #1252121](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1252121)

If you make your way through all the comments on both bug reports you'll be sure to find multiple solutions that work for some, and do not work for others.

Everyone has their own theory as to why this bug is happening.

The problem may possibly lie within the logind D-Bus object, where "PreparingForSleep" is still set to "true" after the suspend/resume cycle.